# Can't install phpMyAdmin on CentOS 7 via shell

Tags: php, apache, shell, phpmyadmin, centos

```
yum -y install phpmyadmin
```

Occurs error:

```
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-2.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: php-zip
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
           php-zip
       Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64 (updates)
           php-zip
       Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.1-2.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           php-zip = 1:1.15.1-2.el7.remi.7.2
       Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.2-1.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           php-zip = 1:1.15.2-1.el7.remi.7.2
       Available: php55w-common-5.5.38-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.31-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.32-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php70w-common-7.0.22-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php70w-common-7.0.23-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php70w-common-7.0.23-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php70w-common-7.0.24-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php70w-common-7.0.25-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php71w-common-7.1.8-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php71w-common-7.1.9-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php71w-common-7.1.9-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php71w-common-7.1.10-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Available: php71w-common-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-zip
       Installed: php-common-7.2.0-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
           Not found
       Available: php-common-7.2.0~RC6-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm lamer at setting up a LAMP server, but looks like the problem is in different modules. Any problem solutions or suggestions?

How I have installed php 7.2:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum -y install php php-mysql php-gd php-ldap php-odbc php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-snmp php-soap curl curl-devel php-mcrypt php-pecl-ap
```

P.S OS is CentOS 7

Comment: you should use valet-linux its better than lamp if you want to run multiple domains like this.dev my.dev according to folders where you park the valet you will able to install everything before that valet installed. Example i have park the valet in Sites folder, then if i create Sites/anim/ then if you open anim.dev in browser it will send all data of Sites/anim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**php-pecl-zip**-1.15.2-1.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 is the right extension.

I recommend you disable webtatic which raise conflicts.
Try to install php-pecl-zip first

I also recommend with recent php version to install phpMyAdmin from "remi" repository which is much more recent (4.7) than EPEL version (4.4).

```
yum-config-manager --disable webtatic
yum install php-pecl-zip
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: That did the trick! But i didn't use the first command `# yum-config-manager --disable webtatic`