# Can't install phpmyadmin 4.8.3 on CentOS 7: --skip-broken rpm- Va --nofiles --nodigest

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos7

I have installed php 7.2 and mysql 8.

I just can't install phpmyadmin 4.8.3 due to the following errors:

```
# yum install phpmyadmin
...
Error: Paquete: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-3.el7.noarch (epel)
           Necesita: php-zip
           Disponible: php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php-pecl-zip-1.15.3-1.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.3-1.el7.remi.7.2
           Disponible: php-pecl-zip-1.15.4-1.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.4-1.el7.remi.7.2
           Disponible: php56u-common-5.6.37-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php56u-common-5.6.38-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php70u-common-7.0.31-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php70u-common-7.0.32-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php71u-common-7.1.20-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php71u-common-7.1.21-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php71u-common-7.1.22-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php72u-common-7.2.8-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php72u-common-7.2.9-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Disponible: php72u-common-7.2.10-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (ius)
               php-zip
           Instalado: php-common-7.2.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
               No encontrado
           Disponible: php-common-7.2.10-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
               No encontrado
 Podría intentar utilizar el comando --skip-broken para sortear el problema
Podría intentar ejecutar: rpm- Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
# rpm -qf $(which php)
-> php-cli-7.2.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

yum clean, enable repo ... etc. but nothing works.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: just install php-zip before running again this installation

Comment: @LelioFaieta `# yum install php-zip` I get the following message: `The package php72u-common-7.2.10-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 is obsolete with php-common-7.2.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64, which is already installed
Nothing to do`

Comment: you are trying to add it via the wrong package... find the way to add it and you will work

Comment: or download and install manually (it is just a bunch of php files) instead of using a package

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47954089/1883256) and it worked! I only applied: `# yum install php-pecl-zip` & `# yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin`

Answer (score 5):

Try this command bellow, it should works

```
yum install php-pecl-zip
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```

Answer (score 1):

You have php **7.2.11** installed from remi-php72 repository which is NOT enable.

Simply enable it before trying to install additional modules, as explained by the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
```

And you will also take benefit of new minor version update (currently: **7.2.15**)